# Rename Docker Volume on Docker Desktop

Tags: docker

Is it possible to rename a docker volume? I want to change the volume names of the existing container. I see that `config.json` and `hostconfig.json` has the volume details in it.

```
docker run -di -p 8083:443 -v app_main_db_test_1:/var/lib/pgsql/data  -v app_main_conf_test_1:/var/www/ ubuntu
```

I want to change `app_main_db_test_1` to `app_main_db` and  `app_main_conf_test_1` to `app_main_conf`

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know, there are no ways of renaming docker volume so far. There is an [open GitHub issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31154), which indicates there is no solution to the topic yet.

But there are a few useful ways to do so. Since you are saying you use Docker Desktop, you could check [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31154#issuecomment-360531460):

```
docker volume create --name <new_volume>
docker run --rm -it -v <old_volume>:/from -v <new_volume>:/to alpine ash -c "cd /from ; cp -av . /to"
docker volume rm <old_volume>
```

Which should do exactly what you are planning to do.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. Thanks to this [github post](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31154#issuecomment-360531460).

```
# Create new Volume for DB and copy files from old volume
docker volume create --name app_main_db 
docker run --rm -it -v app_main_db_test_1:/from -v app_main_db:/to alpine ash -c "cd /from ; cp -av . /to"

# Create new Volume for conf and copy files from old volume
docker volume create --name app_main_conf
docker run --rm -it -v app_main_conf_test_1:/from -v app_main_conf:/to alpine ash -c "cd /from ; cp -av . /to"


# Start the container using new volumes
docker run -di -p 8083:443 -v app_main_db:/var/lib/pgsql/data  -v app_main_conf:/var/www/ ubuntu

# Delete old volumes
docker volume rm app_main_db_test_1
docker volume rm app_main_conf_test_1
```

Comment: This just obliterated my existing volume. Great. Thanks Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't try this on a production machine, however on my dev machine (ubuntu), i had two containers:

```
docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     v1_sail-mysql
local     v2_sail-mysql
```

I wanted to switch volumes like this

```
mysql_1 -> v1_sail-mysql (originally v2_sail-mysql)
mysql_2 -> v2_sail-mysql (originally v1_sail-mysql)
```

My docker volumes are located in /home/docker/volumes, in your case it might be /var/lib/docker/volumes

I just renamed the volumes

```
mv v1_sail-mysql v1_sail-mysql-tmp
mv v2_sail-mysql v1_sail-mysql
mv v1_sail-mysql-tmp v2_sail-mysql
```

Restarted the containers which indeed switch the containers

Answer (score 0):

With Docker Desktop official extension https://open.docker.com/extensions/marketplace?extensionId=docker/volumes-backup-extension you can "clone" volumes. That will help you copy with a new name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).